# Expression for "work productively"

Tags: expressions

Say you're having a chat with someone and as they're about to leave, they mention that they're about to do a particular task.

How do you wish them a productive time, besides "Go kick some ass!"?

Or is this just something not done by English speaking folk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your most general en safe options will probably be:

> "Go for it."

And:

> "You can do it."

*Crushing it* is a common expression used when someone is doing their job particularly well, or exceeding all of their goals. Unlike the literal definition of the word “crush” (to destroy with force to the point of injury), “crushing it” has an extremely positive connotation.

In your case you could use:

> "Go crush it."

*Killing it* has a similar meaning to *crushing it*, but it's probably wise to stay away from a phrase like "Go kill it".

In a more competitive setting this could work highly motivating for the receiver:

> "Show them who's boss."

If you feel like the receiver isn't 100% confident about the task he/she is about to perform, for example when it's his/her first time, you could throw in a more supportive:

> "You got this." And optionally add: ", this is your game."

---

*For the final two options below, I think there's quite a 'risk' of the receiver not knowing what you are talking about, but I think they are technically correct. And if the receiver does know them they could be highly appreciated. But I would say they're your less 'safe' options.*

If it's a task that has been on his to-do list for a while and he finally gathered the motivation to do it, you could refer to Mark Twain's (Briand Tracy has written an entire book about it):

> "Go eat that frog."

If it's a task with which in the ideal outcome brings in money for the company and you want to make him/her feel like a valuable team player:

> "Bring home the bacon."

Hope this helps.

Comment: I thought 'you can do it' as well. And then I thought - how English that is - gentle encouragement that implies that maybe you - can't - do it, rather than, say, the overt American style mentioned of 'go kick ass!'. I found that funny! (Which means, I'm rolling around laughing...!)

Comment: Some people (Gretchen Rubin refers to them as 'rebels') tend to work the hardest when you tell them they can't do it. So in case of an English rebel you might get the best results by telling them they can do it ;)

Answer (score 1):

I just found a possible alternative: 'Make the most of time!'. It can be seen [here](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=57681) translated from the Spanish sentence 'Aprovecha el tiempo!' (it's perfectly suitable for your purpose).

It's also proposed 'Take advantage of every minute!' but I'm not sure of it. This sounds way too polite for your situation. Could someone verify if this is also correct please?

Comment: I guess that could work, but it's not really common.

Answer (score 1):

"Get 'er done!" is perhaps the one I've heard most commonly.  Personally, I tend to say things like "Stay off Facebook!", "Good luck!", or "Have fun!" (for irony).

Comment: Yeah, I've actually heard "Get 'er done!" before. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could just say "I hope you are productive," or "be productive," or "I hope you get a lot done."

The word that came to mind, however, that hasn't been mentioned in this post is **efficient.**

The OED defines this as (generally referring to a machine or a system, but it can just as well apply to a resource, such as a person):

```
achieving maximum productivity with minimum wasted effort or expense.
```

For example, if I accomplished much in a short period of time, I would say I was very productive with my time because I was working efficiently.